# Save images from folder location to entry

Tags: safecracker, channel-images, crop

I want my users to upload and crop images, when creating a new entry using Channel Form.

I'd love to use Channel Images for all of my photo management, but since I'm not happy with it's crop tool - which is way too cumbersome for my clients - I want to integrate an external cropping solution.

Now, I'm able to save cropped images to a folder on the server, but how can I assign those images to the entry being created?

Currently I'm thinking about grabbing the URL of the saved image and putting it in a hidden field during the entry creation process, but I'm not quite sure, how to do this in practice.

I've also purchased Photo Frame, but it's not a real replacement for Channel Images and it doesn't seem to be in active development any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using external tool, consider using Channel Images with CE Image.

Channel Images is perfect tool for image gallery tied to channel entry, and CE Image will give you extended editing possibilities.

Comment: Well,that's exactly my problem. I have both of these addons and while they are nice for handling images in templates, their front-end functionality is either sub par or (in the case of CE Image) non-existent. So, please don't mention any addons! I have tried them all. :)

Comment: If you've a solution in place to crop and the filename is exactly the same as the one uploaded in CP. Why not use the filename function in EE and hard code your custom URL into it?